# Collision Checking between collision object and object attached to the robot

Tags: ros, moveit, planning-scene

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have writen a node for attaching a collision object to the planning scene. I am using the `Apply Planning Scene` service for that. Here is my node:

```
        Vector3d b(0.001, 0.001, 0.001);
        moveit_msgs::AttachedCollisionObject attached_object;   // to attach the object to the robot
        moveit_msgs::CollisionObject remove_object; // to remove the object from the world
        geometry_msgs::Pose pose;  
        moveit_msgs::PlanningScene planning_scene;
    
        attached_object.link_name = "tool0";    //the link to which the object will be attached
        attached_object.object.header.frame_id = "tool0";     // w.r.t. the link to which it is attached
        attached_object.object.operation = attached_object.object.ADD;
        std::string touch_links = "motor";
      attached_object.touch_links.push_back(touch_links);  
    
     ROS_INFO("Attaching kinematic_e1 to motor and removing it from the world.");
          attached_object.object.id = "kinematic_e1";
          shapes::Mesh* m = shapes::createMeshFromResource("package://mitsubishi_rv6sd_support/meshes/objects/kinematic_e1.stl",b);
          shape_msgs::Mesh mesh;
          shapes::ShapeMsg mesh_msg;  
          shapes::constructMsgFromShape(m, mesh_msg);
          mesh = boost::get<shape_msgs::Mesh>(mesh_msg);  
          pose.orientation.w = 1.0;
          attached_object.object.meshes.push_back(mesh);
          attached_object.object.mesh_poses.push_back(pose);
          remove_object.id = "kinematic_e1";
          remove_object.header.frame_id = "base_link";
          remove_object.operation = remove_object.REMOVE;

  planning_scene.world.collision_objects.clear();
  planning_scene.world.collision_objects.push_back(remove_object);  //This step removes the object from the world 
  planning_scene.robot_state.attached_collision_objects.push_back(attached_object); //This step attaches the object to the robot
  planning_scene.is_diff = true;    //Update the planning scene as a diff
  planning_scene.robot_state.is_diff = true;    //Update the robot state as a diff
  
  //Using services to make changes to the planning scene
  ros::ServiceClient planning_scene_diff_client = node_handle.serviceClient<moveit_msgs::ApplyPlanningScene>("apply_planning_scene");
  planning_scene_diff_client.waitForExistence();

  moveit_msgs::ApplyPlanningScene srv;
  srv.request.scene = planning_scene;
  planning_scene_diff_client.call(srv);
```

---

Then I try to check the `AllowedCollisionMatrix` for the attached object (`kinematic_e1` in this case). I use the `GetPlanningScene` service to get a copy of the allowed collision matrix. But when I query the entry names in the matrix, I cannot find the name of the attached object in the list.

```
    moveit_msgs::PlanningScene currentScene;
   moveit_msgs::GetPlanningScene scene_srv;
    scene_srv.request.components.components = scene_srv.request.components.ALLOWED_COLLISION_MATRIX;
    if(!client_get_scene_.call(scene_srv))
    {
        ROS_WARN("Failed to call service /get_planning_scene");
    }
    else
    {
        ROS_INFO_STREAM("Initial scene!");
        currentScene = scene_srv.response.scene;
        moveit_msgs::AllowedCollisionMatrix currentACM = currentScene.allowed_collision_matrix;

        ROS_ERROR_STREAM("size of acm_entry_names before " << currentACM.entry_names.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < currentACM.entry_names.size(); i++)
      ROS_ERROR_STREAM(" Name =  " << currentACM.entry_names[i]);
        ROS_ERROR_STREAM("size of acm_entry_values before " << currentACM.entry_values.size());
        ROS_ERROR_STREAM("size of acm_entry_values[0].entries before " << currentACM.entry_values[0].enabled.size());
```

How can I find the attached object in the allowed collision matrix?

I dont know if this is related but when I give a pose goal where a definite collision between the robot and the robot attached link wil occur, the planning fails. This kind of tells me that MoveIt! plans taking into consideration the attached object. It appears correctly in `RViz` as well. Then why does the name of the attached object not show up in the allowed collision matrix?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/257795/collision-checking-between-collision-object-and-object-attached-to-the-robot/) by [bhavyadoshi26](https://answers.ros.org/users/26692/bhavyadoshi26/) on ROS Answers with karma: 95 on 2017-03-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think that you have to modify the planning scene's allowed collision matrix  and then call the applyPlanningScene service.

The allowed collision matrix is manually updated. In my experience(from indigo version) the planning scene contains only the allowed collsions from the SRDF model and then it is up to you to update it accordingly.

---

Originally posted by [angeltop](https://answers.ros.org/users/29793/angeltop/) with karma: 351 on 2017-03-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [v4hn](https://answers.ros.org/users/4809/v4hn/) on 2017-03-27**:
This is correct. If you want to allow collisions with attached objects, you have to add them to the ACM explicitly. If there is no entry for an object in there, MoveIt will always take collisions with them into account. You can use `collision_detection::AllowedCollisionMatrix` to simplify the update

**Comment by [BrettHemes](https://answers.ros.org/users/20527/bretthemes/) on 2017-05-17**:
If this is the case, could you please elaborate on the difference between `touch_links` and entries in the ACM?

**Comment by [angeltop](https://answers.ros.org/users/29793/angeltop/) on 2017-05-18**:
I am not sure what the exact difference is, but I know that in order to allow collisions between two links, one has to update manually ACM. Maybe touch_links is used only for attaching an object on the robot and not for planning.

**Comment by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) on 2018-08-07**:
@v4hn Doesn't that mean that every time you attach an object to a gripper, the attached object and the gripper link are automatically in collision?

**Comment by [v4hn](https://answers.ros.org/users/4809/v4hn/) on 2018-08-20**:
Sorry, I never noticed the replies to my comment. :/
`touch_links` is an independent mechanism for allowing collisions with attached objects.
The vector is supposed to contain all the links of the gripper that actually touch the object.

However, this will not add the object to the ACM.

**Comment by [v4hn](https://answers.ros.org/users/4809/v4hn/) on 2018-08-20**:
So if you wish to add additional allowed collisions later on, you have to manually add the object to the ACM.

@fvd: it depends on whether you filled in the touch_links. The `link_name` is always allowed to collide with the object.