# How to implement c++ application for checking collision between collision object and object attached to the robot in moveit2?

Tags: moveit, ros-humble

I am implementing a c++ app for checking collision between collision object and object attached to the robot in moveit2.
I can find collision between a robot and a collision object that is not attached to robot by using PlanningScene::checkCollision method.
However I can't find collision between collision object and object attached to the robot by this PlanningSceme::checkCollision method.
I know there is an old discussion  [here](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/79793/collision-checking-between-collision-object-and-object-attached-to-the-robot): but i can't find useful information.

## What have i tried:

This are the steps of my attempt:

1. start robot with moveit_config
2. make a planning_scene instance like:

   ```
    robot_model_loader::RobotModelLoader robot_model_loader(node);
    const moveit::core::RobotModelPtr & kinematic_model = robot_model_loader.getModel();
    planning_scene::PlanningScene planning_scene(kinematic_model);
   ```
3. using planning_scene_interface.applyCollisionObject to add a collision object A(A box). Object A is not colliding with the robot.
4. using planning_scene.setPlanningSceneDiffMsg to add object A to planning_scene
5. using planning_scene_interface.applyAttachedCollisionObject to attach a object B(robotiq hand mesh model) to robot. In this timming I can confirm object A colliding with object B from the rviz window.
6. using attachBody method defined in RobotState to attach object B to RobotState instance.
7. execute planning_scene.checkCollision

however collision_result shows there is no collision between object A and object B.
Also, i have tried calling  /check_state_validity service directly.
But same result that it can find collision between collision object and robot, but not collision between collision object and object attached to the robot.

Here is my code

```cpp
#include <moveit/move_group_interface/move_group_interface.h>
#include <moveit/planning_scene_interface/planning_scene_interface.h>
#include <moveit_visual_tools/moveit_visual_tools.h>

#include <geometric_shapes/shape_operations.h>

#include <memory>
#include <rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp>
#include <thread>
#include <moveit/motion_planning_rviz_plugin/motion_planning_frame.h>


#include <tf2_eigen/tf2_eigen.hpp>


using moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroupInterface;

void addCollisionObject(
  const MoveGroupInterface & move_group_interface,
  moveit::planning_interface::PlanningSceneInterface & planning_scene_interface,
  moveit_msgs::msg::CollisionObject & collision_object,
  planning_scene::PlanningScene & planning_scene)
{
  collision_object.header.frame_id = move_group_interface.getPlanningFrame();
  collision_object.operation = collision_object.ADD;
  // Add the collision object to the scene
  auto ret = planning_scene_interface.applyCollisionObject(collision_object);

  moveit_msgs::msg::PlanningSceneWorld psw;
  psw.collision_objects.push_back(collision_object); //moveit_msgs::msg::CollisionObject collision_object;
  auto ps = moveit_msgs::msg::PlanningScene();
  ps.world = psw;
  ps.is_diff = true;
  //planning_scene.setPlanningSceneMsg(ps);
  planning_scene.setPlanningSceneDiffMsg(ps);

  std::cout << "ret add obj:" << ret << std::endl;
}


// Function to convert moveit_msgs::msg::AttachedCollisionObject to moveit::core::AttachedBody
//moveit::core::AttachedBody convertToAttachedBody(
Eigen::Isometry3d convertPoseToIsometry3d(const geometry_msgs::msg::Pose & pose)
{
  Eigen::Isometry3d object_pose;
  object_pose.translation() << pose.position.x, pose.position.y, pose.position.z;
  object_pose.linear() = Eigen::Quaterniond(
    pose.orientation.w,
    pose.orientation.x,
    pose.orientation.y,
    pose.orientation.z
  ).toRotationMatrix();

  return object_pose;
}


int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
  // // Initialize ROS and create the Node
  rclcpp::init(argc, argv);
  auto const node = std::make_shared<rclcpp::Node>(
    "hello_moveit", rclcpp::NodeOptions().automatically_declare_parameters_from_overrides(true));

  // Create a ROS logger
  auto const logger = node->get_logger();
  const std::string arm_group = "ur_manipulator";
  const std::string base_link = "base_link";

  // We spin up a SingleThreadedExecutor for the current state monitor to get
  // information about the robot's state.
  rclcpp::executors::SingleThreadedExecutor executor;
  executor.add_node(node);
  auto spinner = std::thread([&executor]() {executor.spin();});

  // Create the MoveIt MoveGroup Interface
  auto move_group_interface = MoveGroupInterface(node, arm_group);
  RCLCPP_INFO_STREAM(logger, "frame_id: " << move_group_interface.getPlanningFrame());
  // Create collision object for the robot to avoid
  robot_model_loader::RobotModelLoader robot_model_loader(node);
  const moveit::core::RobotModelPtr & kinematic_model = robot_model_loader.getModel();
  planning_scene::PlanningScene planning_scene(kinematic_model);
  moveit::planning_interface::PlanningSceneInterface planning_scene_interface;

  ////////collision object import/////////////////
  [&move_group_interface, &planning_scene, &planning_scene_interface] {
    moveit_msgs::msg::CollisionObject collision_object;
    collision_object.id = "wall1";
    shape_msgs::msg::SolidPrimitive primitive;

    // Define the size of the box in meters
    primitive.type = primitive.BOX;
    primitive.dimensions.resize(3);
    primitive.dimensions[primitive.BOX_X] = 0.1;
    primitive.dimensions[primitive.BOX_Y] = 1.0;
    primitive.dimensions[primitive.BOX_Z] = 1.0;
    collision_object.primitives.push_back(primitive);

    // Define the pose of the box (relative to the frame_id)
    auto const obj_pose = [] {
        geometry_msgs::msg::Pose obj_pose;
        obj_pose.orientation.w = -0.707;
        obj_pose.orientation.x = 0.0;
        obj_pose.orientation.y = 0.0;
        obj_pose.orientation.z = 0.707;
        obj_pose.position.x = 0.3;
        obj_pose.position.y = 0.35;
        //obj_pose.position.y = 0.15;
        obj_pose.position.z = 1.1;
        return obj_pose;
      }();
    collision_object.primitive_poses.push_back(obj_pose);
    addCollisionObject(
      move_group_interface, planning_scene_interface, collision_object,
      planning_scene);
  }();

  moveit::core::RobotStatePtr current_state = move_group_interface.getCurrentState(10);
  ///////////attach hand///////////////////
  [&] {
    geometry_msgs::msg::Pose grab_pose;
    grab_pose.orientation.w = 1.0;
    grab_pose.position.z = 0.0;

    moveit_msgs::msg::CollisionObject object_to_attach;
    object_to_attach.id = "robotiq_hand";
    object_to_attach.header.frame_id = move_group_interface.getEndEffectorLink();

    Eigen::Vector3d scale(0.001, 0.001, 0.001);
    std::string resource =
      "package://hello_moveit/cad/robotiq_gripper/robotiq_2F_adaptive_gripper_rough.STL";
    shapes::Mesh * m = shapes::createMeshFromResource(resource, scale);
    shape_msgs::msg::Mesh co_mesh;
    shapes::ShapeMsg co_mesh_msg;
    shapes::constructMsgFromShape(m, co_mesh_msg);
    co_mesh = boost::get<shape_msgs::msg::Mesh>(co_mesh_msg);
    object_to_attach.meshes.push_back(co_mesh);
    object_to_attach.mesh_poses.push_back(grab_pose);
    object_to_attach.operation = object_to_attach.ADD;

    //moveit::planning_interface::PlanningSceneInterface planning_scene_interface;
    moveit_msgs::msg::AttachedCollisionObject acobj;
    acobj.link_name = move_group_interface.getEndEffectorLink();
    acobj.object = object_to_attach;
    std::vector<std::string> touch_links;
    touch_links.push_back("wrist_3_link");
    acobj.touch_links = touch_links;

    planning_scene_interface.applyAttachedCollisionObject(acobj);

    current_state = move_group_interface.getCurrentState(10);
    shapes::ShapePtr m_ptr(m);
    std::vector<shapes::ShapeConstPtr> shapes;
    shapes.push_back(m_ptr);
    Eigen::Isometry3d zero_pose(Eigen::Isometry3d::Identity());
    auto shape_pose = convertPoseToIsometry3d(grab_pose);
    EigenSTL::vector_Isometry3d shape_poses;
    shape_poses.push_back(shape_pose);

    current_state->attachBody(
      object_to_attach.id, zero_pose, shapes, shape_poses,
      touch_links, acobj.link_name);

  }();

  collision_detection::CollisionRequest collision_request;
  collision_request.group_name = "ur_manipulator";
  collision_request.contacts = true;

  collision_request.max_contacts = 100;
  collision_detection::CollisionResult collision_result;

  collision_detection::AllowedCollisionMatrix acm = planning_scene.getAllowedCollisionMatrix();
  acm.print(std::cout);
  planning_scene.checkCollision(collision_request, collision_result, *current_state);
  RCLCPP_INFO_STREAM(
    logger, "Current state is " << (collision_result.collision ? "in" : "not in")
                                << " collision");

  if (collision_result.collision) {
    for (const auto & entry : collision_result.contacts) {
      const auto & key = entry.first;
      RCLCPP_INFO_STREAM(logger, "collision between:" << key.first << ", " << key.second);
    }
  }

  auto collision = planning_scene.isStateColliding();
  RCLCPP_INFO_STREAM(
    logger, "Current state is " << (collision ? "in" : "not in")
                                << " collision");

  // Shutdown ROS
  rclcpp::shutdown();
  spinner.join();
  return 0;
}
```

Do i miss something?
Thanks advance.